# Scapy DHCP retrieving offered IP address

Tags: python, scapy

I've successfully created a DHCP discover, Offer and Request in Scapy.
I was wondering if it is possible for me to retrieve the offer DHCP IP address, saving it to a variable where I will be able to request for it specifically in my DHCP Request using Scapy.
I've tried using sniff but it doesn't seem to retrieve any IP address as follows :

```
sniff(iface=myiface, filter="port 68 and port 67")
```

Are there any methods to retrieve the offered IP?
Thanks

Comment: "it doesn't seem to retrieve any IP address as follows" => Is this a problem with capturing the packet or with parsing the packet once saved to a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this already. For anyone else who needs help on this.
Basically BOOTP in the sniffed packet contains the offered IP address and to retrieve the address. Simply do this:

```
pckt.getlayer(BOOTP).yiaddr #pckt is the sniffed packet
```